# Mittag Leffler function Laplace transforms with Mathematica

Tags: special-functions, integral-transforms

Mathematica seems not to to know the basic Laplace and inverse Laplace relation

$$\mathcal L(E_\alpha[−λt^α],t)(s)=\frac{s^{α-1}}{λ+s^α}$$

surrounding the Mittag Leffler function ([`MittagLefflerE`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MittagLefflerE.html)). The evaluations

```
LaplaceTransform[MittagLefflerE[alpha, -lambda t^alpha], t, s]

Integrate[ Exp[-s t] MittagLefflerE[alpha, -lambda t^alpha], {t, 0, Infinity}]

InverseLaplaceTransform[s^(alpha - 1)/(lambda + s^alpha), s, t]

1/(2*Pi*I)* Integrate[ Exp[s t] s^(alpha - 1)/(lambda + s^alpha), {s, -Infinity, Infinity}]
```

all fail. However, when setting $\alpha=1$ the correct Laplace transform $1/(\lambda +s)$ of the expontential function is recovered.

Has anybody had more success with this kind computations?

Comment: It seems to me that the current symbolic support for general Mittag-Leffler functions is quite limited.

Answer (score 2):

It seems to be an unsupported feature indeed. I received this answer from Wolfram Research in the discussion pages:

https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/1090476

> Thank your these examples.
>
> The failure of [`LaplaceTransform`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/LaplaceTransform.html) and other functions to evaluate for
>   [`MittagLefflerE`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MittagLefflerE.html) in your examples is a limitation that we hope to
>   address in a future release.
>
> I apologize for the inconvenience caused by this limitation.
>
> Sincerely, Devendra Kapadia, Wolfram Research, Inc.