# Adding a module to teach Mathematica the Laplace transform of particular Mittag-Leffler functions

Tags: probability-or-statistics, programming, special-functions, integral-transforms

Mathematica 11.3 is not aware of a useful Laplace transform

```
LaplaceTransform[t^(-a) MittagLefflerE[a, a, t^a], t, s]
```

which for `0 < a <= 1`, `Re[s] > 1`  should be

```
(s^a - 1)^(-1)
```

as easily checked

```
s = 2; a = 1/2; Print[
 NIntegrate[
  Exp[-s t] t^(-a) MittagLefflerE[a, a, t^a], {t, 0, Infinity}], "=",
 (s^a - 1)^(-1) // N]
```

(a similar remark was made in [Mittag Leffler function Laplace transforms with Mathematica](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/145872/mittag-leffler-function-laplace-transforms-with-mathematica) )

I guess  it should be possible to add this simple rule via a module. This would allow for example inverting Laplace transforms which are rational  functions of `s^a`, which may be one of the most basic applications of these particular Mittag-Leffler functions.

Comment: Did you already send this suggested Laplace transform to Support?

Comment: I just added this remark to  https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/2084173